# Colossally abundant numbers and the Riemann hypothesis

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-hypothesis

*[This question followed up from a question on [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4168449/934420).]*

Writing Robin's inequality for the Riemann hypothesis (RH) as $$\frac{\sigma(n)}{n \ln\ln n} < e^\gamma \;,$$ we can take logarithms and introduce a function $$s(n) = \ln \frac{\sigma(n)}{n \ln\ln n}$$ such that the bound becomes $s(n) < \gamma$.
This is convenient, because if we know the prime factorisation $n = \prod_{q} q^{k_q}$ of a candidate number, we can rather easily compute $$s(n) = \sum_{q} \ln \frac{q^{k_q+1} - 1}{q - 1} - \sum_{q} k_q \ln q - \ln\ln \sum_{q} k_q \ln q \;,$$ without too much numerical trouble.

If the RH is false, the inequality will fail to hold for a colossally abundant number.
Theorem 10 of Alaoglu & Erdős (1944) gives a simple enumeration of the prime exponents of the colossally abundant number associated with a particular $\epsilon > 0$, $$k_q(\epsilon) = \left\lfloor \frac{\ln \frac{q^{1+\epsilon}-1}{q^{\epsilon}-1}}{\ln q}\right\rfloor - 1 \;.$$
Since all we need to compute the function $s(n)$ are a large list of primes $q$ and their exponents $k_q$, we can pick any $\epsilon > 0$, for example at random, compute the complete list of nonzero $k_q(\epsilon)$, and obtain $s(n)$ rather straightforwardly.
The result of a random draw as function of $\epsilon$ is shown here:

[image]

[image]

Interestingly, we seem able to make the following observation:

> *For $\epsilon < 0.01$, the function $s(n)$ is monotonically increasing as $\epsilon$ approaches zero.*

Is this true?

I think it is pretty straightforward that $s(n)$ is piecewise constant as a function of $\epsilon$. If $s(n)$ changes because the exponent $k_q$ increases (is it always just one of the $k_q$?), the change is $$\delta s = \ln \frac{q^{k_q+2} - 1}{q^{k_q+2} - q} - \ln\ln\ln nq + \ln\ln\ln n \;.$$ It's easy to find the largest $q$ given $\epsilon$, but are there bounds for $k_q$ and $n$ to show $\delta s > 0$?

If the observation was true, it would mean that the RH can be disproved with the limit $\epsilon \to 0$ of $s(n)$ alone (which is of course still a very hard problem). This seems a very analytical problem however, and makes me wonder how and where the structure of the primes matters in this.

**Edit:**

Let me ask a different question:
We do have that $$ \limsup_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sigma(n)}{n \ln \ln n} = e^\gamma \;.$$
Does it follow that $\limsup_{\epsilon \to 0} s(n) = \gamma$?
Is the conjecture therefore equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis?

---

Comment: Why did you edit out the link to the m.se question?

Comment: The answer to your first question is NO; the left hand side of your first indented equation is the Grönwall function G(n). It is not monotonic. The answer to the second one, if I understand correctly what conjecture of yours you are talking about, is not quite. RH is equivalent to $G(n) < e^\gamma$ for $n$ sufficiently large - you need the equivalent for $s(n)$. I need a bit of time to try to put together some kind of an answer to post, with references and all. Hopefully I get back to you soon.